# How to create a C# List with const content?

Tags: c#, c++, list, constants

In C#: Is there a way to define the content of a List const/readonly like in C++?

C++ Example:

```
List<const Content> listWithConstContent;
```

Comment: C# does not support immutability like that.

Comment: There's a pre-release for System.Collections.Immutable which would have  ImmutableList<T>. I have not tried it but MS says you can get it from Nuget.

Comment: Another problem: we're working with 4.4.x.

Comment: probably the closest thing is a ReadOnlyCollection https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474(v=vs.110).aspx .. far from perfect though

Comment: Can you describe the constraint you actually wish to express? Because many people believe that `const` in C++ does something different than what it actually does.  Do you want an immutable variable referring to the list, do you want a list whose item set cannot be mutated, or do you want a list of items that cannot be mutated but the list can be mutated; what exactly do you want? Also, what do you already know about `Content`? Is it a value type, a reference type, what?

Comment: @Eric: I want a list of items that cannot be mutated but the list can be mutated.

I'd like to provide a list of for example state information to the user of a facade class. The user should be not able to change the state and I don't want to copy it before - I like to provide const refrences to the state info. What the end user does with the list is not important - will be created on each request.

About Content (or state information) itself I know everything and I'm able to edit/change the Content class code. Content consumes a lot of memory and it costs a lot of CPU to calculate it new.

Comment: There is no "const reference" in C#. My suggestion is that you make a public interface with all your "reader" methods, make `Content` implement that interface, and then hand out a `List<IReadOnlyContent>`. Then make `Content` an internal type. So now your internal code can party on the content all you want, but the external code can only get at it via the public interface.

Comment: @Eric Lippert: this is to much additional work and makes the code more complex. Assume we had just 10 of this Content classes with a ~50 properties... Is there a good reason why const is not supported in C# like in C/C++ or other languages? Some people fill papers about const correctness.

Comment: @SLaks: can you write your comment as an answer? I'm think your comment is the correct answer! You have earned your points ;-)

Comment: @tommy_tee: Const in C/C++ is deeply flawed. It provides no guarantee that I actually want. All a const reference says is "you can't change this", but the guarantee that I want is "this won't change". But it does impose restrictions that I don't want; for example, it imposes the restriction that I cannot refactor a pure const method into one which is implemented by updating a private memoizer. There are far better ways to achieve immutability guarantees than putting const in the type system.

Comment: @Eric Lippert: We work in a team and provide interfaces for each other - if the content of a list could be constants then I'm sure that my mates want try a workaround to "cast it away" or what else. Const is a very simple way to make a interface "secure" and protects you from mistakes... I think const in C++ isn't flawed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# does not support immutability like that

Answer (score 1):

The `List<T>` class in the .NET framework is mutable. There is no equivalent of that C++ feature either in C#, or the CLR.

If you want an immutable list, then you need to use eg [`ImmutableList<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn467185(v=vs.111).aspx)

Comment: Is the content of an ImmutableList immutable or just the list itself?

Comment: @tommy_tee, the list itself is immutable. If `T` is a mutable type though, then the content of the elements can change. Changing the content is frowned upon as bad practice, but is not enforced by the complier or runtime.

Comment: Who cares about bad practice? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

*Read-only* and *immutable* are different properties. Which one do you expect?

- If you need readonlyness, there is no support for it from C# type
  system. You need to expose your object through interface that does
  not allow to mutate state of this object.
- If you need immutability, you need to design your class to work that way. There is no way to
  make it magically immutable.

Comment: Could you explain, please, in what way immutable and read only are not the same?

Comment: current time is read-only - you cannot change it, you can only check it. 
current time is not immutable - it mutates every time quantum

Comment: That's a really good example. I'd never understood the immutable isn't same as read-only claim before. I now do. Thanks.

Comment: `List<T>` does have a member, [`AsReadOnly`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78dcd75.aspx).